# Can't play movie in MPMovieplayercontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I can't play a movie in `MPMovieplayercontroller`. I have searched a lots on google but every time I got a black screen. Also I tried to check `isPreparedToPlay` property but it is always false.

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

[self.moviePlayer setContentURL:[self.videos objectAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"Playing videos : %@", [self.moviePlayer contentURL]);

 NSLog(@"Playing videos : %@", [[self.moviePlayer contentURL] absoluteString]);

[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, 320, 460)];
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
//self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType    = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
/*[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];*/  
[self.moviePlayer play];
```

First NSLog print something weird (why there is "..." ?):

```
/Users/Athos/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/15855707-E728-4542-8DAA-3B71362D7DB6/data/Containers/Data/Applicati ... unny.mp4
```

But second one is good (i check manually if the file was there:

```
/Users/Athos/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/15855707-E728-4542-8DAA-3B71362D7DB6/data/Containers/Data/Application/2ACD0002-1A1E-484C-B4E4-9486EBCFF74A/Documents/BuckBunny.mp4
```

Do you have any clue ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this first:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920197/how-to-check-whether-a-video-or-audio-file-format-is-playable-in-iphone-programa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"%@/BuckBunny.mp4"];    
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

if(movieURL!=nil){
    [self.moviePlayer setContentURL:movieURL];
    [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[self.moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self.videos objectAtIndex:0]]];
// Use FileURLWithPath
```